# How to apply Direct Airside Transit Visa (DATV) for Indians

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, datv

Hi I am travelling to India in December of this year from the USA via London (Dallas - London - Hyderabad) for H1b stamping. My current stamped F1 visa is expiring in November. But I have valid I797 until 2021. So i have to take Direct Airside Transit Visa (DATV) to pass through London airport.

Could somebody please tell me how to apply for DATV visa from USA?

If somebody had already been in the same situation and applied for DATV, could you please share your experience here.

Comment: If you search ‘apply for a UK visa in the US’ you’ll find this official site https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa

Answer (score 1):

The DATV visa is if you don’t pass through immigration.

Note: If you have to re-check your bags you will pass through immigration.

You will need to have your biometrics taken as mentioned on the [GOV page](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa). The page also provided information on how to apply from the USA.

Comment: Thanks Daniil, Yes, I will not re check my bags. I did go through the website you mentioned above. Will the Biometrics appointment is included as part of filling this application? or we have to book biometrics seperately?

Comment: @Hari you are suitable for this visa then, it usually takes 15 days. No problem :)

Comment: Will the Biometrics appointment is included as part of filling this application? or we have to book biometrics seperately?

Comment: @Hari the biometrics have to be booked separately

Comment: could you please give me the link to book biometrics

Comment: @Hari The guidance says you book your biometric appointment when you apply online. AFAIK it’s part of the application process, there’s no link to enable you to book it separately.